# DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(100)

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Django web site running a mini CMS we've built internally years ago, it's using postgresql. When saving a simple title and a paragraph of text I get the following error:

```
value too long for type character varying(100)
```

The weird thing is, not a single column is varying(100) they are all 200 or 250, even the default Django ones have been changed from the 100 to 200 due to a [re-opened ticket mentioned here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8548)

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I can bet money you have a `models.SlugField` without length set. The default length is [50 characters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield), most likely it's not enough for your use case.

Change it to `models.SlugField(max_length=255)` and migrate your database schema.

Comment: You got it. I didn't think this was the issue because by default Django stores them as varying(50) but one of the dependencies in the project had a model varying(100) for the slug fields; I overlooked it.

Comment: @michael that was impressive. I was pretty stuck.

Comment: So like slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255), and then migrate on heroku?

Comment: Yes, then run `./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate`

Comment: In my case it was a CharField with max_length set to 10. ... I changed it into a TextField and it worked smoothly...

Comment: Arg, why is it not telling what field is the problem? All my slug  and file fields have larger max_size...

Comment: Great Answer Sir. I was even thought about that and also manually set the slug field but that was not still working. But when I changed that it started to work. As you win the bet I gave you +10.

Comment: I didnt have SlugField , but with the same Error

Comment: Shut up and take my money!

Answer (score 42):

I also had this problem when using a filefield and was scratching my head for a while. Of course the default FileField instances are created with a 100 character limit.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield

Comment: for those who are working with long path of a FileField (e.g. very long file name or path), this may be the problem rather than the SlugField. CMIIW.

Answer (score 18):

This is an error message from Postgres and not django.

You seem to have changed the length of the field in the `models.py`, but that doesn't change the database length which was created when you did a `manage.py syncdb`.

You have to alter the length of the field in the database, directly.

Comment: I didn't change them only in the models. I ran south as we normally do when we changed DB properties and we've since migrated, we double checked all the tables manually in postgres and there are no remnants of varying 100 anywhere. I am confused.

Answer (score 5):

**Django 2.1**

I encountered this problem while switching from sqlite3 to postgresql.
Remove the migration files in each app's migrations folder except **__init__.py**
Then re-run migration

```
(venv)myapp$python manage.py makemigrations
(venv)myapp$python manage.py migrate
(venv)myapp$python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: it didn’t help me, the creation of migration does not depend on the database.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with django-autoslugfield
I was using a similar package and then switched over to django-autoslugfield

I was getting this error:
`value too long for type character varying(50)`

despite the fact that my models.py had:

`slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=255, populate_from='name', unique=True)`

and in my db the it the type was
`character varying 255`

once i remove `max_length=255` from the field i.e.

`slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True)`

then it worked fine

Comment: It was the same for me. But when I delete max_length, it doesn't change anything. I get the same error: value too long for type character varying(50). When I switch to django's own slugField then it works with max_length attribute.

Answer (score 2):

i went through this same error. and when i made changes in the modele, i kept having the same error.

Here is how i fixed it.
It might be necessary to skip few migrations for the program to only use the migration where changes have been made for the CharField max_lenght.

for that you have to run

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

to see which migrations have not been made.

then you skip them until you get to the last with the command

```
python manage.py migrate <app> 000_migration_number --fake
```

Answer (score 2):

its just enough to remove max_lenght from password field .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I realize the question is already answered but for others that come here when looking for the error message:

In my case the problem was that my table name exceeded 50 characters. Apparently this is not allowed. Changing the table name solved the problem.

Read more here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18959

Answer (score 1):

[Michael Samoylov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465623/michael-samoylov)'s answer pointed me in the right direction. I had the same error come up, except it was with a FileField.

Fields have a max_length, even if you have not explicitly set a max_length. Increase the value so that your data fits to avoid the error.

In my case, the data was too large to reasonably store in the database. I resorted to saving my file to disk, then saving the file path in the database.

Comment: yah, I think Django should by default use the max SQL size instead of making assumptions of whats a safe size and let the user override the default by adding a `max_length` to their field instead.

Answer (score 1):

For the FileField and the ImageField, from the Django docs:

FileField instances are created in your database as varchar columns with a default max length of 100 characters. As with other fields, you can change the maximum length using the max_length argument.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I wanted to set `max_length` to a lower value on a `FileField`.
Interestingly, the error message states `value too long` but in my case the value was too short.

The **solution was to set back the `max_length` to its old value**. It's quite weird that the migration couldn't be done.
I also had to delete the wrongly generated migrations files and rerun `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not `SlugField`, `FileField`, or any other field mentioned here--scroll back to where the migration got stuck in the terminal. For me it was `AddField`

Good talk.

Answer (score 0):

First, try setting max_length to something reasonable on all applicable field types in your model.

For example: `MyText = models.CharField(max_length=2000)`

If you don't set a max_length, your database might be applying a default max_length, shorter than the length of your input data, causing your `value too long for type character` error.

If that doesn't work and you started in SQLite and changed databases to PostgreSQL, the previous migrations from SQLite might be interfering with the new PostgreSQL migrations.

Go into the migrations folder for your project and delete the old migration files to get a fresh start. Then try makemigrations and migrate again :)

Comment: Hi Annaleise! Thanks for commenting. I think migrations are not dependent on a particular database engine. Do you have an example?? Either way, your comment, as it is now, is not answering this particular question

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I don't believe that migrations are supposed to be database dependent. However, I had the same error as the original poster, despite max_length being set for all fields. The only action that works was deleting the previous migrations and starting again. I will edit my post to better answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

predefined fields in model.py creates the problem. Extend it to desired length, i think problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I manually intervened in the migrations file. I adjusted the max_length for the affected field to accommodate the larger data size (in this case, from 50 to 255). By doing this, I was able to successfully migrate both changes without any issues.

Steps Taken:

```
Go to the migrations file associated with your app.
Locate the migration where you increased the max_length.
In that migration, find the field in question and adjust its max_length to a value that accommodates your data size (e.g., from 50 to 255).
```

Answer (score -1):

The value can be 100 or 25 or 17 whatever , the reason behind that is models , search where you have added that particular length(17,25) and you will get the bug ! ,

You are trying to impose a field length more than mentioned one.

This solved my issue , I hope it will help you too

Comment: The issue was not related to this. The default max length for a slug is 50 (or maybe was at the time when I first asked this question) but the slug was longer than 50 so it was creating the bug. Adding a max_length to the slugfield fixed the issue

Comment: Sir i don't have any slud field in my project but the error was still there ,,...closely looking the model i find that ...and it resolved my issue