# Model field length constraint with validation response in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am validating data from a request in django's rest framework with data validation in the serializer.  I need all error messages to be sent in a single response.

On sending a string that is too long, i get the error:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(3)
```

In my model I've defined the max length of the character field as 3 (max theoretically needed).

I've added validation in the serializer to catch requests with too many characters:

validators.py

```
class CustomUserValidators():

    errors_to_return = {}
    def val_role(self, role):
            if len(role) > 3:
                self.errors_to_return["role_length"] = "Ensure this field has no more than 3 characters."
```

serializers.py

```
from Sea.validators import CustomUserValidators
class LagoonUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer, CustomUserValidators):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'role',)


    def validate(self, attrs):
        self.val_role(attrs['role'])

        if len(self.errors_to_return) > 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(self.errors_to_return)

        return attrs
```

models.py

```
class SeaUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    role = models.CharField(_('Role'), max_length=3)
```

But the request still returns the error (`value too long...` as above).  I expected the erorr to be caught in the serializer and the values not passed to the model, why is the value ever reaching the model?

I have researched this, and all the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036102/databaseerror-value-too-long-for-type-character-varying100) say make the field length 255.  This doesn't answer why the value is ever being tested by the model in the first place, and doesn't explain what happend if somehow a longer than expected value does end up in the request.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: This is really minor, but it's a REST framework for Django, it is not "Django's REST framework". The Django project doesn't own or control the REST framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with different approach and take advantage of serializer's validation.

You can specify custom field-level validation by adding .validate_field methods to your Serializer.

So you can add the following method to your serializer.

```
def validate_role(self, value):
    if len(value) > 3:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Ensure this field has no more than 3 characters")
    return value
```

And remove `CustomUserValidators` completely.

As mentioned in the comment, you can move the validation to a utility function and use it everywhere you need.

```
def validate_user_role(value):
    return 0 < len(value) <= 3
```

You can place this function in a separete module if you like and then you use in your serializer:

```
def validate_role(self, value):
    if not validate_user_role(value):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Ensure this field has no more than 3 characters")
    return value
```

Another, simpler solution to consider is to use serializer's CharField attributes and do this:

```
class LagoonUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    role = serializers.CharField(min_length=1, max_length=3)
```

This will validate your input without implementing the validate_role method.

Comment: Appreciate the help,  it's not in the question, but i have to validate role fields in multiple requests, that's why I have used a custom class, is this not considered good practice?   (thanks for the input)

Comment: Yes, sure it is. You can just create utility function to validate the input and call it in this validate_role method and then you can use everywhere you need. That would be one possible approach.

Comment: Do you fancy adding an example of how one would use an utility function in this case ?

Comment: updated the answer as requested.  But consider the last approach in my answer - that seems to be the easiest and simplest ( unless you plan to have some more sophisticated validation )